# Python: run SimpleHTTPServer and make request to it in a script

Tags: python, python-2.7, server, simplehttpserver

I would like to write Python script that would:

1. Start SimpleHTTPServer on some port
2. Make a request to the server and send some data via POST
3. Run script via shell in interactive mode and interact with it

Right now the code looks like this:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import urllib
import urllib2

# Variables
URL = 'localhost:8000'
PORT = 8000

# Setup simple sever
Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()

# Getting HTML from the target page
values = {
    'name': 'Thomas Anderson',
    'location': 'unknown'
}
data = urlilib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
html = response.read()
```

The problem is that once I run my script

```
python -i foo.py
```

It prints `serving at port 8000` and then freezes. I bet this is something trivial for Python gurus here, but help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the server as a *different process*, that will allow you to run the rest of your script.

I would also rather use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) than urllib.

```
import SocketServer
import SimpleHTTPServer

import requests
import multiprocessing

# Variables
PORT = 8000
URL = 'localhost:{port}'.format(port=PORT)

# Setup simple sever
Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print "Serving at port", PORT

# start the server as a separate process
server_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=httpd.serve_forever)
server_process.daemon = True
server_process.start()

# Getting HTML from the target page
values = {
    'name': 'Thomas Anderson',
    'location': 'unknown'
}

r = requests.post(URL, data=values)
r.text

# stop the server
server_process.terminate()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for, but couldn't get due to python-experience limit.

Comment: One thing I've noticed, is an error while trying to execute this: socket.error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permit
ted

Comment: This is most likely due to the fact, that you are not shutting down your http server, at least in your example. Please see my answer for more detail.

Comment: Do you get this error when you try to restart the script? So yes, as @NarūnasK  suggests, it may be the case that the server is still running and therefore the port `8000` is taken. The answer was edited.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively run it in the separate `thread`:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import urllib2
from threading import Thread
from datetime import time

# Variables
URL = 'localhost:8000'
PORT = 8000

# Setup simple sever
Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print "serving at port", PORT
def simple_sever():
    httpd.serve_forever()

simple_sever_T = Thread(target=simple_sever, name='simple_sever')
simple_sever_T.daemon = True
simple_sever_T.start()

while not simple_sever_T.is_alive():
    time.sleep(1)

# Getting test file
req = urllib2.Request('http://localhost:%s/test_file' % PORT)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print response.read()
httpd.shutdown()
```